# How to make React Native mobile application faster?

Tags: android, performance, react-native, redux, stack-trace

React Native mobile **application is working very slow on every click**.
I am using react native `v0.40.0` and following are the dependencies of my project.

```
{
    "analytics-react-native": "^1.1.0",
    "apisauce": "^0.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "flow-bin": "^0.36.0",
    "geolib": "^2.0.22",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "lodash.range": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "raven-js": "^3.13.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.40.0",
    "react-native-apple-healthkit-rn0.40": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-blur": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-button": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "^1.17.3-beta",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.4.4",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.4.5",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-global-props": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.15.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.25.1",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-maps": "0.15.2",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.4.4",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.7.2",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "3.38.0",
    "react-native-segmented-android": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "2.1.4",
    "react-native-stars": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-tableview-simple": "0.16.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-zendesk-chat": "^0.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "recompose": "^0.20.2",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

I did profiling with stacktrace in android studios, and found that mqt_js is one of the reason which takes more time on every UI clicks. You can check stacktrace report [here](https://ufile.io/88yfh)

Can anybody help me in solving this performance issue.?

Comment: Are these delays occurring in production builds of your app? Or just development builds? Have you tried using something like `redux-logger` to see all of your actions being fired?

Comment: Its delaying in both production as well as development builds. I already using `redux-logger`.

Comment: Try taking systrace on IOS and it will probably show something.
From the attached traces (of android), there is no frame drop seen in UI thread (all green F), but there seems to be a lot of work going on in JS thread(mqt_js) after click. Unfortuantely systrace is broken on android to give details of JS thread. Attach ios systrace if you can.

Answer (score 18):

Here are some advices for optimization react-native:

1. Parsing and serializing (such as `response.json()` or `JSON.stringify`) blocks js thread, so all JS animations and handlers (such as `onScroll` and `onPress`, and of course `render` method) suffer from this. Try to load from backend only data that you need to show.
2. Use native animations (`useNativeDriver: true` parameter) where it is possible, and try not to use `onScroll`. Also, consider using [react-native-reanimated](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated) for animations.
3. Optimize you `render` method and try to make its calls as rare as possible. It is called when component's props or state changed.
4. Understand how `PureComponent` and `React.memo` work and try to use them where necessary. But keep in mind that they also can slow the app down if not used correctly.
5. Always use `StyleSheet` for styles, it cashes them and replaces with style id (integer), so styles are passed to native side only once and then style ids are used.

Bad:

```
// style object is created on every render
render() {
    return <View style={{flex:1}}/>
}
```

Good:

```
render() {
    return <View style={styles.flex}/>
}

// style is created once
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    flex: { flex: 1 }
});
```

6. Same with functions.

Bad:

```
// onPress handler is created on every render
render() {
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigator.navigate('SignIn')}/>
}
```

Good:

```
render() {
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressSignIn}/>
}

// onPressSignIn is created once
onPressSignIn = () => {
    this.props.navigator.navigate('SignIn');
}
```

7. [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of all operations on client should be constant. Enumerate arrays as less as you can. Always use `Object` and `Set` instead of `Array` where it is possible. Use pagination when you need to load big amounts of data from server / database, leave sorting and other heavy calculations for server.

For example if you often need to get objects by id, it is better to use:

```
let items = {
    "123": { id: "123", ... },
    "224": { id: "224", ... }
};

let item = items["123"];
```

instead of usual array:

```
let items = [
    0: { id: "123", ... },
    1: { id: "224", ... }
];

let item = items.find(x => x.id === "123");
```

8. Check out this doc: https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance

Answer (score 7):

This is a very **broad** and **opinion based** question, but I'll try to highlight the `most common points` and suggestions based on the `profiler` you have listed.

Looking at your stack trace, the main problem lies with the `UI Thread` inside your package name ie `com.fitspot.app.debug`.

As mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#identifying-a-culprit).

> in order to display a frame, all our UI work needs to be done by the end of that 16ms period.

Once the boundary interval is set to `16ms`, then you can see that the `mqt_js` or the `JS Thread` is taking far longer than `16ms` for one cycle, meaning your `JS Thread` is running constantly.

In the current `profiler`, it is unclear what processes are executed in your `JS Thread`, therefore it is clear that the problem lies mainly in your `JS Code` and not the `UI Thread`.

There are multiple ways to make the `react-native` app faster which is well documented in this [page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html). Here's a **basic** gist to the same.

- Error and warning messages are provided in the mode `dev=true`, you can *disable them across the app* for a better performance.
- Remove all the `console.log` statements from your app, as it causes a [`bottleneck`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck_(engineering)) on the JS Thread. You can use this plugin to remove all the `console*` statements as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements), in your .babelrc files as

  ```
  {
    "env": {
    "production": {
    "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
   }
  }
  ```
- You need to `componentize` your project structure, and use `Pure Components` , to rely on `props` and `state` only, use `immutable data structures` for faster comparisons.
- For the `slower navigation transitions`, you might want to check the `navigation library` code, since mostly they have a `timeout` for `default transitions`. As a workaround you may consider building your own `transitioner`.
- If you're using `Animations` in your codebase, you might consider setting `nativeDriver=true`, which would reduce the load on your `JS thread`. Here's a well explained [example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated.html).
- You also might want to check the **Profiling**, to check the `JS Thead` and the `Main Thread` operations, well explained on this page.
- Other stuff includes, not `requiring/importing` the module, which is not necessary, importing only `classes` required, and not the `whole component`.
- Also , you dont need `external libraries` to make `simple UI components`, since their performance is much slower than the native elements of `react-native`. You may consider using [`styled-components`](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) to componentize your `UI`

Answer (score 4):

1. Use [Flatlist](https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6) over Scrollview:

   - add `initialNumToRender={number}` prop to Flatlist, as it will show only those components which are visible on screen and detach the other components
2. Use [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html) in Flatlist renderItem (In your case it will Each Card), so that they will only render whenever their props get changed.
3. Check whether your component is re-rendering again and again in order to test put console either in render() or in ComponentWillRecieveProps and if this is happening then use ShouldComponentUpdate.
4. Remove console.log from  render() and ComponentWillRecieveProps.

Make these changes and you see your performance is much better than before.

Answer (score 2):

There can be various reasons which makes the react-native app slower. I would suggest the following key points that can help:

1. Prefer `dumb components` over `class components` wherever possible.
2. Try using `redux`, it is a powerful state management tool that can provide you  the best code, if implemented properly.
3. Use tools like `react-monocole` and `appr`. Guide to [react-monocole](https://github.com/team-gryff/react-monocle).
4. Generate the signed apk, the debugged react-native app has additional features  in it. Here's a guide to [generate signed apk](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html).

Comment: just follow this guide https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43

Answer (score 1):

If `mqt_js` is the main cause of performance issue, that means in every click, the JS thread of your app has too many things to do at once. Communication between JS business logic and underlay native realm is done asynchronously, the more actions need to be finished in JS side when a button is pressed, the slower the app will be.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49554378/2404452) given by Pritish Vaidya already hits the nail on the head. I just want to include 1 more point about the usage of `redux` in your app. If your app's data flow is mainly done using `redux` then you can check for following things:

- If there are too many redux actions happening on each clicking event, try to remove unnecessary ones or prioritise actions triggering important animations first, then triggering other actions once new RN components finished rendering. You can see which actions are bottomneck ones by `redux-logger`.
- Break components listening to redux's store into smaller ones, with each listening to a different part of the store. So if redux's store is updated, only a small group of components should be rerendered instead of everything.
- Use memoized selectors to deal with frequently updated data. [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect) can help you in this case.