# React-Native Slow Performance in Physical Android Device

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

So I have built my app, still developing it. I tested in a real physical android phone which has 7.0 version, but in physical device application is much slower than in geny motion simulator..

So I deleted all console.logs, so it improved the performance bit but still its slower.. Do you have any ideas, why it may be happening, or what I should do about it? Because in official documentation they also suggest it to try as .apk instead of developer mode. Any suggestions about it, maybe a testing program or something?

Plus I have different animations and they are very smooth in geny motion simulator device but in physical device they are at least 2 times slower.. Also my android device is very new, it has 3 GB memory.. My device is : Xiaomi Red Mi 5a

Sorry if question looks very dull but maybe some experts who published many react-native projects can suggest us useful solutions :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49495327/6749177 check this out

Comment: yeah useful link, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. There is technical details to improve performance in React-Native you can find it in google but when I released my app as .apk, performance improved dramatically! I am even surprised.. So unless you try with release version of your app(instead of debugging version), you shouldnt be sure!

Check details here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android